# WCF Service hosting in IIS6 or IIS7 and calling it from a Windows form

Tags: wcf, iis

I have created a WCF service application in VS2010 and done all the necessary implementations in it.

I have also created a windows form which calls this service (have added service reference). Now bcos it is self hosting, its working perfectly fine.

I want to move the service to the IIS and check the clients working from multiple locations (to note the speed of the operation performed). I have checked everywhere in the net for how to host a WCF service in IIS6 (or7) but to no clarity.

Please let me know how i can publish the service from my VS 2010 and created a virtual directory etc etc so that my client's reference points to the IIS hosted service

Comment: Is the service defined in a library or in the self hosted .exe?

Comment: Not in a service library, i used the WCF Service application project and my interface and svc file are in it, so i guess it is in a self hosted.exe...I am not able to get how to create the folder which i will set to my virtual directory of IIS

Comment: Ahh sorry must have mis-read your question - I thought you said you were self-hosting. So you are currently running under the development web server and want to move to IIS?

Comment: I am beginner in WCF..all i did was to create a client(windows form) , then create a WCF service appl project, defined and implemented the contracts, then in my client, i added a service reference of the WCF service(localhost, my machine is only hosting it), then i created the WCF client object and called the relevant operations..

Comment: Now i want to move the service to the IIS, so that i can share my client to multiple users in different location around the world.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to run Visual Studio as Admin

Go to the WCF project properties and in the Web tab say you want to use the local IIS server. Then click the button to create the virtual directory

You will need to change the address that the client talks to to be the new IIS hosted location

Comment: but my IIS server is not local, its on another machine...i guess the VS2010 option is only for local IIS servers...I am a general webservice developer and have published the service into a file folder and then set the folder as virtual directory in IIS...can i do the same for WCF services?

Comment: Yes - but you will need to ensure its running the right version of .NET and that the .svc extension is mapped in the web application

Comment: but i dont have a web application..i just want to call an IIS hosted WCF service from a windows form client..

Comment: When you create the virtual directory in IIS you can also make it an application but a virtual directory should be fine here - just tdo what you have for other webservices - just make sure the App Pool is running the right version of the framework